# Why does apt-add-repository adds PPAs to sources.list.d directory, but repositories links to sources.list file

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, repository

What is the reason of that `apt-add-repository` adds PPAs to `sources.list.d` directory, but repositories links to `sources.list` file?

Comment: APT manages it quite easily. Why would it be better otherwise?

Comment: It doesn't matter what is better, but why they get saved in two different places?

Comment: That I cannot answer as I haven't the foggiest idea.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, (one could check APT's history), the original way was to let PPAs get added to `/etc/apt/sources.list`. But, as time went on, and the number of possible additional PPAs expanded beyond expectation, it became clear that modifying `/etc/apt/sources.list` wasn't the best choice. The `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` method was added (maintaining backward compatibility by looking at `/etc/apt/sources.list`, too). Many packages do it (look at `echo /etc/*.d /etc/*/*.d`, read `man run-parts`, although it doesn't apply to PPAs)

Comment: Thank you, but what I still don't understand, is why does `apt-add-repository` adds only PPAs to sources.list.d but not the links? Is that mean that the best practice is to add PPAs using `apt-add-repository`, and the links using `echo http://XXX > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/XYZ.list`